# Drupal 7 caching my form and printing old cached fields (Varnish/Memcache)

Tags: caching, drupal-7, memcached, varnish

I have a profile2 form called by drupal_get_form - though after its been edited and saved, the fields still display the old information for awhile. How can I turn caching off here? I'm using memcache/varnish/apc btw.

I'm also printing these fields elsewhere and get the same problem.. I would rather this be dynamic and fresh for just these fields/forms.. any ideas on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to exclude cache_form from memcache with:

```
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
```

in your settings.php file

Comment: Hi ghloogh:
Currently my settings.php looks like this:
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

Do you think memcache is causing this rather than varnish?

Comment: I guess, that you passed through Varnish cache to be able to edit content. If not, just try to restart Varnish or purge cache for this url only, to see what happens with 'cached' field.

Comment: Hi ghloogh: I just turned off Varnish and it seems to be working fine now. It was even causing problems with my Rules (entity not found and so on). Is there a way to disable caching for this form and certain content types?

Comment: Normally Varnish doesn't know backend application logic, so to disable caching of some content, you should let him know what is it. 

For example, if you want to pass 'stories' CT and it has URLs like '/stories/some-title-blahblah', then you need to say to Varnish something like
if (req.url ~ "^/stories/") {
return(pass);
}
Also, you need to check that you not caching POST requests.
Could you show your vcl?

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was quite useful!

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: by putting this setting in settings.php we tell drupal to get form cache from inside drupal and not outside?